# Google Maps AutoComplete API - Listener for start and destination

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, textfield, addeventlistener

I am working on a google maps application and tried to implement the autocomplete API.
It is working for 1 textfield.

Is it possible to add the same for the destinationfield without copying the code?
I added the listener as in the documentation
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

Here is the listener for the changed event,
but I don't know, if I can bind it for 2 textfields..

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocompleteStart, 'place_changed', function() {
   //...
)};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the function multiple times, a simple implementation:

```
(function(o,e,f){
  for(var i=0;i<o.length;++i){
    google.maps.event.addListener(o[i],e,f);
  }})([autocompleteStart,autocompleteEnd], //array with autocomplete-objects
       'place_changed',                    //event-type
       function(){/* do something*/}       //handler-function
     );
```

Comment: sorry for answering late,
I have succeeded in implementing it :)
thanks